# XAMPP(LAMPP)'s phpmyadmin throwing error #2002

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have just installed XAMPP(LAMPP) about a hour ago and I am continously searching for the error I am getting on while opening `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`(phpmyadmin). The screen of the error is as follows: 
[image: sorry for the tabs!]

So how can I resolve the error?

I searched on the net and found that my mysql.sock file is missing but I am not getting on how to fix that issue. So how can I bring my mysql.sock file back?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart MYsql.
check if the LAMP server is configured properly.
For more help please ask your query.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you include an answer with instructions on how to do that? For example, what is the command to restart MySQL, and how can one check if the LAMP server is configured properly? Thanks.